# How to run setup() before startTest() in unittest python

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I want to listen to some piece of code as part of my `startTest()` but only after my `setUp()`.

Is this possible by any means

Comment: Why can you not just put that 'piece of code' at the end of your `setUp` method? Would also be helpful if you could post some relevant code

Comment: yes, that kind of works